# View locks acquired during query execution (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server-2012, locking, execution-plan

Query execution plan does not show the locking details by default, is it possible to view the locks, along with the type, acquired during the execution of a query?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> is it possible to view the locks, along with the type, acquired during the execution of a query?

Yes, for determining locks,

1. You can use **[<kbd>beta_lockinfo</kbd> by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/sqlutil/beta_lockinfo.html)**

   > `beta_lockinfo` is a stored procedure that provides information about processes and the locks they hold as well their active transactions. `beta_lockinfo` is designed to gather as much information about a blocking situation as possible, so that you can instantly find the culprit and kill the blocking process if the situation is desperate. Then you can sit back and analyse the output from `beta_lockinfo` to understand how the blocking situation arose and figure out what actions to take to prevent the situation from reoccurring. The output from `beta_lockinfo` shows all active process as well as passive processes with locks, which objects they lock, what command they last submitted and which statement they are executing. You also get the query plans for the current statements. Normally, you run `beta_lockinfo` to look at the output directly, but there is also an **archive mode** where the data is saved to table. This is not the least useful, if you want someone to send you the output from `beta_lockinfo` at a site you don't have access to yourself.
2. Another method is to use **[<kbd>sp_whoIsActive</kbd> by Adam Machanic](http://whoisactive.com)** with `@get_locks = 1`

   ```
   EXEC sp_WhoIsActive 
   @filter = '', 
   @filter_type = 'session', 
   @not_filter = '', 
   @not_filter_type = 'session', 
   @show_own_spid = 0, 
   @show_system_spids = 0, 
   @show_sleeping_spids = 1, 
   @get_full_inner_text = 0, 
   @get_plans = 1, 
   @get_outer_command = 1, 
   @get_transaction_info = 0, 
   @get_task_info = 1, 
   @get_locks = 1,   ----------> 1 = ON (get lock info); 0 = OFF
   @get_avg_time = 0, 
   @get_additional_info = 0, 
   @find_block_leaders = 0, 
   @delta_interval = 0, 
   @output_column_list = '[dd%][session_id][sql_text][sql_command][login_name][wait_info][tasks][tran_log%][cpu%][temp%][block%][reads%][writes%][context%][physical%][query_plan][locks][%]', 
   @sort_order = '[start_time] ASC', 
   @format_output = 1, 
   @destination_table = '', 
   @return_schema = 0, 
   @schema = NULL, 
   @help = 0
   ```

Comment: thanks, the above stored procs are great for db admin scenarios, but, do you know of any alternatives for query optimization scenarios. I am trying to understand the locking behavior of an insert query in development environment (which does not have a lot of data, so query does not run very long). I would like to see the all the locks acquired by a query after its executed, I am interested in seeing the lock plan, similar to how query plan works.

Comment: Since you are using sql server 2012, at a query granular level, you should look into XEvents - [Determine Which Queries Are Holding Locks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677357(v=sql.105).aspx). This will give you a good start.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I look at locks by process/table/lock type:

```
SELECT 
    HostName,
    "OS UserName",
    Login, 
    spid, 
    "Database", 
    TableID,
    "Table Name_________", 
    IndID, 
--  [Index Name],
    "Lock Type", 
    "Lock Mode", 
    Status, 
--  Resource,
    Count(*) AS "Lock Count"
FROM (
    SELECT
        Convert(VarChar(30), RTRIM(P.HostName)) AS HostName,
        Convert(VarChar(30), RTRIM(P.nt_UserName)) AS "OS UserName",
        Convert(VarChar(30), Suser_SName(p.sid)) AS Login, 
        Convert(SmallInt, req_spid) AS spid,
        Convert(VarChar(30), DB_Name(rsc_dbid)) AS "Database",
        rsc_objid AS TableID,
    Convert(VarChar(30), Object_Name(rsc_objid, rsc_dbid))
        AS [Table Name_________],
        rsc_indid AS IndID, 
        CASE SubString (lock_type.name, 1, 4) 
            When '' Then 'None'
            When 'DB' Then 'Database'
            When 'FIL' Then 'File'
            When 'IDX' Then 'Index'
            When 'TAB' Then 'Table'
            When 'PAG' Then 'Page'
            When 'KEY' Then 'Key'
            When 'EXT' Then 'Extent'
            When 'RID' Then 'Row ID'
            When 'APP' Then 'Application'
            Else SubString (lock_type.name, 1, 4)
        END AS "Lock Type",
        Case SubString (lock_mode.name, 1, 12)
            When NULL Then 'N/A'
            When 'Sch-S' Then 'SCHEMA (Stability)'--'SCHEMA stability lock'
            When 'Sch-M' Then 'SCHEMA (Modification)'--'SCHEMA modification lock'
            When 'S' Then 'SHARED'--'SHARED Lock acquisition'
            When 'U' Then 'UPDATE'--'UPDATE lock acquisition'
            When 'X' Then 'EXCLUSIVE'--'EXCLUSIVE lock granted'
            When 'IS' Then 'SHARED (Intent)'--'INTENT for SHARED lock'
            When 'IU' Then 'UPDATE (Intent)'--'INTENT for UPDATE lock'
            When 'IX' Then 'EXCLUSIVE (Intent)'--'INTENT for EXCLUSIVE lock'
            When 'SIU' Then 'SHARED (Intent UPDATE)'--'SHARED lock with INTENT for UPDATE'
            When 'SIX' Then 'SHARED (Intent EXCLUSIVE)'--'SHARED lock with INTENT for EXCLUSIVE'
            When 'UIX' Then 'UPDATE'--'UPDATE lock with INTENT for EXCLUSIVE'
            When 'BU' Then 'UPDATE (BULK)'--'BULK UPDATE lock'
            Else SubString (lock_mode.name, 1, 12)
        END AS "Lock Mode", 
        SubString(lock_status.name, 1, 5) AS Status,
        SubString (rsc_text, 1, 16) AS Resource
    FROM 
        Master..SysLockInfo S
        JOIN Master..spt_values lock_type on S.rsc_type = lock_type.number
        JOIN Master..spt_values lock_status on S.req_status = lock_status.number
        JOIN Master..spt_values lock_mode on S.req_mode = lock_mode.number -1
        JOIN Master..SysProcesses P on S.req_spid = P.spid
    WHERE
            lock_type.type = 'LR'
        AND lock_status.type = 'LS'
        AND lock_mode.type = 'L'
        AND DB_Name(rsc_dbid) NOT IN ('master', 'msdb', 'model')
    ) AS X
WHERE TableID > 0
GROUP BY 
    HostName,
    "OS UserName",
    Login, 
    spid, 
    "Database", 
    TableID,
    "Table Name_________", 
    IndID, 
    "Lock Type", 
    "Lock Mode", 
    Status
ORDER BY
    spid, "Database", "Table Name_________", "Lock Type", Login
```

Comment: It's a great answer and it's such a shame that it uses compatibility views. Come on, it's 2015!

Answer (score 3):

You can view acquired locks history in "Messages" tab after running this:
DBCC TRACEON(1200, 3604, -1)
But BEWARE, it is enabling those trace flags GLOBALLY, so do not forget to turn them off as soon as you do not need them.

Answer (score 2):

You can view the locks for a session using sp_lock or sys.dm_tran_locks.
In both ways you can filter by the session.
You can also use Extended Events to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can view the locks and its type during the query execution via

1. Adam mechanics's SP_whoisactive [click here to view](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/)
2. Moreover if you want to create a block report with you can do with help of trace as explained [here](http://www.brentozar.com/sql/locking-and-blocking-in-sql-server/)

Comment: `performance counters` will just give you instance wide behaviour. The OP wants at query level.

Comment: @Kin, thanks , just removed the extra info :)